# Difference between >> and >>> in verilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, data-operator

What is the difference between `>>` and `>>>` in verilog/system verilog? I know that `==` tests for only 1 and 0, while `===` tests for 1, 0, X, Z. So how is that similar to the shift operator?

Answer (score 17):

It is not similar to `==`/`===`, if the left hand operand is signed then `>>>` performs sign extension.

```
reg signed [9:0] b = 10'sb11_0101_0101;
reg signed [9:0] a_signed;
reg        [9:0] a_unsigned; 

always_comb begin
  a_signed   = b >>> 2;
  a_unsigned = b >>  2;
end
```

Result:

```
#a_signed   1111010101
#a_unsigned 0011010101
```

Example on [EDA Playground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/NRm).

Comment: Wow, that is exactly the opposite of the meanings of the Java `>>` and `>>>` operators... wicked.

Comment: Verilog was 10 years before Java. :P

Comment: @dave_59, but signed values (aside from the 32-bit `integer` type) and the arithmetic shift operators were only introduced to Verilog in Verilog-2001.

Comment: Verilog already had `>>` to mean logical shift in 1985 (taken from Pascal, which is from 1970). So it had to use `>>>` for arithmetic shift.

Answer (score 12):

According to IEEE1800-2012 `>>` is a binary logical shift, while `>>>` is a binary arithmetic shift.

Basically, arithmetic shift uses context to determine the fill bits, so:

- arithmetic right shift (`>>>`) - shift right specified number of bits, **fill with value of sign bit if expression is signed**, otherwise fill with zero,
- arithmetic left shift (`<<<`) - shift left specified number of bits, fill with zero.

On the other hand, logical shift (`<<`, `>>`) always fill the vacated bit positions with zeroes.

For example:

```
a = 5'b10100;
b = a <<< 2; //b == 5'b10000
c = a >>> 2; //c == 5'b11101, 'cause sign bit was `1`
d = a <<  2; //d == 5'b10000
e = a >>  2; //e == 5'b00101
```

Comment: The results of this example depend on the declaration of `c`: if you use `reg [4:0] c`, you'll get `5'b00101`, not `5'b11101`.  Updating the example to clarify the types would be useful, I think.